# warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness

Tags: c

My compiler(gcc) is showing the warning

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s{
     unsigned char *p;
};

int main() {
    struct s a = {"??/??/????"}; //warning
    printf("%s",a.p);
    return 0;
}
```

warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness

please help me to why is this warning comes.

Comment: String literals are not of type `unsigned char*`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - I was about to post that as the answer after editing his post (which Mystical beat me to) - do so and I'll upvote

Answer (score 25, accepted):

String literals are not of type `unsigned char*`.

You probably meant to type `const char*` in your struct. If not, you probably do not want to assign a string literal to it without making it `const`, because it is illegal to modify the memory in which string literals reside.

Answer (score 9):

As @Seth Carnegie said, string literals are of type `char*`, not `unsigned char*`. So you can avoid this warning with an explicit type cast. i.e.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s{
     unsigned char *p;
};

int main() {
    struct s a = {(unsigned char *)"?""?/?""?/????"}; // no warning
    printf("%s",a.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Changed string literal to remove the possible [trigraph](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-trigraphs-977)

Comment: `??/` is the [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) for `\ `. That means that the string will come out to be `"\\????"`, so with the `'\'` escaped, it becomes `"\????"`. I don't know if trigraphs are replaced inside string literals though so all that may be wrong. +1 for spotting it.

Comment: Gotta watch out for trigraphs, because `"wtf??!"` will turn in to `"wtf|"`. It's an old construct from a bygone era of keyboards that were missing certain keys.

Comment: @Chris so then they are replaced inside string literals?

Comment: Just read up on them. `gcc` only does trigraph substitution if you specify one of the `-trigraph`, `-ansi`, or `-std` options. I have updated the code sample above to avoid the issue entirely

Comment: Actually I'm not entirely clear on that one. I never use them myself. I believe they're replaced everywhere (it's rather hard to write a program if you're missing the semicolon key -- trigraphs had better work outside of strings as well as within).

Comment: Shouldn't GCC interpret trigraphs if you compile it with -pedantic? They are still valid C even in C99.

Comment: As a curiousity: from what I heard in first person from "Mr X" who was in the standard committee, trigraphs were introduced in C because some European countries that have more letters than A-Z originally made keyboards where they had removed special symbols like \ | in favour for their national letters.

Answer (score 4):

There may be some cases when change the compiler options should be a reasonable way to solve that.

An example:

You have an API with some prototype like this:

```
void Display (unsigned char * Text);
```

and you want call like this:

```
Display ("Some text");
```

You **may** get the same warning ("pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'Display' differ in signedness").

This warning is due the flag `-Wpointer-sign` that, quoting GNU compiler reference, "*...is implied by `-Wall` and by `-pedantic`, which can be disabled with `-Wno-pointer-sign`*".

Answer (score 2):

Change unsigned char * type to const char*.